# Users are not told why they cannot suggest edits from the review interface when they have too many pending edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, popup

While reviewing First Posts, I came across an answer that was good, but needed some help with the formatting.  When I hit `edit` through the review interface, I received no feedback- no popup, the edit button wasn't disabled, just no reaction.

When I went to the question directly and tried to edit the answer, a popup told me that I was no able to submit an edit because I had too many pending edits.

The reason for me not being able to edit the answer was a confusing mystery from the review interface.  I would like to see a notification given to the user through the review interface as well.

Comment: [2 many bug reports ...](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/812101/2-many-bug-reports)

Comment: Please don't go through questions editing the title length only. You're just adding more things to the review queue. If you want to do this, wait until you have >2k rep, or also edit other things in the questions which require editing.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Do you have an example of an edit you feel I should not have made?  I feel all of the edits I have made have been complete.

Comment: My argument is that edits should be made organically, not by methodically going through certain types of questions. There's really only one place where we do that, and that's for tag burnination. This is especially true when you are below 2k rep, as each of those edits ends up making more work for reviewers.